# Evaluate clustering based on cluster sizes

Tags: cluster-analysis

I am working on a problem where I have to cluster unstructured log messages.
In order to do that, I iteratively go through the logs and try to build generic log templates.
These templates are considered as clusters.

As a result, the only information that I have about these clusters are the generated templates and how many log messages are assigned to each one of them (the cluster sizes).

I have many parameters that I can fine-tune in order to improve the template generation. So I would like to measure the quality of the clustering based on their size.

What objective fuction can I use in order to achieve that ?

My initial thoughts were to measure the spread of the cluster sizes and try to have them be evenly distributed, but also try to minimize the number of clusters of size 1 (or small sizes in general). But I couldn't find a way to formalize this.

Here's an example of an array of cluster sizes and a plot of its sorted values:

```
dict_values([74, 30, 5, 35, 1, 1, 1, 2, 26, 2, 15, 9, 6, 14, 7, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 8, 7, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 19, 3, 43, 2, 2, 5, 2, 11, 1, 2, 3, 2, 18, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 6, 2, 2, 1, 4, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 2, 6, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 16, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 7, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

[image: y: cluster sizes, x: IDs]

As you can see there's quite a lot clusters with small sizes.

Thank you for your help.